# How to separate two id's

Tags: php

How can separate my id's? I want to use my div it in different function. the first id is used in function the other id is used in script

```
<div class="g2 "> 
    <input type="text" id="noPosting number_only" disabled="true" name="post_every" value="" class="txt_r integer-365"/>
</div>
function disableNeverPosting(v) {
        if (v.value == 'no_posting') {
            noPosting.disabled = true;
            }
        else {
            noPosting.disabled = false;
            }
    }
$("input[id='number_only']").keydown(function (e) {
        // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, enter , F5
        if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46,8, 9, 27, 13, 110,116]) !== -1 ||
             // Allow: Ctrl+A, Command+A
            (e.keyCode === 65 && (e.ctrlKey === true || e.metaKey === true)) || 
             // Allow: home, end, left, right, down, up
            (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 40)) {
                 // let it happen, don't do anything
                 return;
        }
        // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
        if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi, What did you mean separate two id's? please elaborate your question more.

Comment: Are you referring to the two different values in the id attribute? Maybe you could just add them to the classes instead?

Comment: please check my updated codes